# How to retrieve content from a cell above another cell when using Filtered Display

Tags: excel-2013

I would like to retrieve the contents of a cell which has been displayed using filters, into a cell that appears below all other filtered cells.
Using =INDIRECT("I" & ROW() - 1) will only retrieve the content for the literal numerical cell, even though that cell is not displayed due to the use of a filter.
Can this be done?

Example:
Filtered Row 1000 - Cell(A1000)="Data"
Row 5555 - Cell(A5555) = "Data from Cell A1000", where Cell(A1000) can be dynamically changed by filtered display options.

Comment: Are you asking a formulas question of a VBA question. Also, it is best to structure your examples using the code markdown format to make it more readable.

Comment: Formula if possible, VBA if required.